# How to make python script keep working after sys.excepthook?

Tags: python, exception, hook, traceback

I want to make custom error handler, after which script will continue working. I tried to use `sys.excepthook = CatchHook`, and I got something like this:

```py
def CatchHook(e,v,t):
    print("{} / {} / {}".format(str(e.__name__, str(v), str(traceback.extract_tb(t)))
    print("Traceback was handled, but script will continue working!")
sys.excepthook = CatchHook
```

But when I run it, it exits. How can I make it work without exiting?

Comment: Have you tried `try` `except` block

Comment: @Joe I need a global hook, to catch everything, including users input to eval()

Answer (score 0):

How I understand you want something like this:

```
def your_script():
    while True:
        try:
            your_code()
        except Exception as ex:
            template = "An exception of type {0} occurred. Arguments:\n{1!r}"
            message = template.format(type(ex).__name__, ex.args)
            print(message)
```

If you want to exit the "while" use break or return

Comment: No, I need sys.excepthook or alternative for it, because I have dynamic code and need to catch **everything** without `try` and `catch` at every line.